# How to make POST call using FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to setup a RESTFUL web service using FOSRestBunble, but I have some problem making POST calls, here's my setup:

app/config/routing.yml

```
rest:
    type: rest
    resource: "routing_rest.yml"
    prefix: /api
```

app/config/routing_rest.yml

```
Rest_User:
    type: rest
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml"
```

AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml

```
rest_application:
    type: rest
    resource:     "AppBundle:Rest"
    name_prefix:  api_
```

AppBundle/Controller/RestController.php

```
class RestController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function testrestAction(Request $request)
    {
        $r = [
            'is'    => 'TEST'
        ];
        return $r;
    }

    public function getArticleAction()
    {
        $r = [
            'is'    => 'GET'
        ];
        return $r;
    }

    public function postArticleAction()
    {
        $r = [
            'is'    => 'POST'
        ];
        return $r;
    }
}
```

I also made PUT and DELETE test methods. so when I do some test call

GET /api/testrest

```
{
    "is": "TEST"
}
```

GET /api/article

```
{
    "is": "GET"
}
```

POST /api/article

```
No route found for "POST /api/article": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD) (405 Method Not Allowed)
```

PUT and DELETE are also fine. Am I missing some configuration?

second problem: if I make a API folder inside Controller folder, I change the namespace for RestController to "namespace AppBundle\Controller\API;" and I update "AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_rest.yml" to

```
resource:     "AppBundle:API:Rest"
```

then I got this message:

```
Can't locate "AppBundle:API:Rest" controller in /var/www/ws/app/config/routing_rest.yml (which is being imported from "/var/www/ws/app/config/routing.yml").
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-option, run `app/console debug:router` (or `bin/console debug:router` if v > 2.8), to list generated routes;

2-option, add `RouteResource` annotation to class (eg. `article`), rename `postArticleAction` to `postAction` and check `POST /api/articles` is responding or not;

3-option, add `article` url explicitly with `@POST` annotation, eg. `/** @Post("article") */`

Comment: I solved debugging the router, basically the automatically generated routes creates /api/articles for postArticleAction method. 
But, if a add a method postArticlesAction, I'll have 2 routes ( api_post_article and api_post_articles) both pointing to /api/articles, and this doesn't make any sense to me, maybe a bug? Anyway thanks for your help and thanks to remind me to use the command line to debug.